# X509Certificate2 - Cannot find the requested object

Tags: c#, x509certificate

Trying some AWS code for using their IoT Core. The lines:

```
var caCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "AmazonRootCA1.crt"));
var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\XXXXXX\iot-dotnet-publisher-consumer\Dotnetsamples\certificates\certificate.cert.pfx", "XXXXX");
```

result in the error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Cannot find the requested object.

I have confirmed that the file does exist in that location. What else could be wrong?

**EDIT** - It's the second operation that is throwing the exception.:

```
var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\XXXXXX\iot-dotnet-publisher-consumer\Dotnetsamples\certificates\certificate.cert.pfx", "XXXXX");
```

Comment: There are two operations in this code.  Which one is throwing the exception?